# Summing the contents of two collections.Counter() objects

Tags: python, counter

I am working with `collections.Counter()` counters.  I would like to combine two of them in a meaningful manner.

Suppose I have 2 counters, say,

```
Counter({'menu': 20, 'good': 15, 'happy': 10, 'bar': 5})
```

and

```
Counter({'menu': 1, 'good': 1, 'bar': 3})
```

I am trying to end up with:

```
Counter({'menu': 21, 'good': 16, 'happy': 10,'bar': 8})
```

How can I do this?

Comment: All you need to do is sum them.

Comment: More specifically, `sum(counters, Counter())` to make sure the sum algorithm starts with a Counter base instead of a simple numeric base.

Comment: @KobeJohn turn comment in answer? it's gold

Comment: Thanks! The gods of python stackoverflow have deemed this question as a duplicate of the more generic dicts question and so I can't add an answer. The linked question does have at least one answer among many that includes the initial value feature of sum().

Answer (score 138, accepted):

All you need to do is add them:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = Counter({'menu': 20, 'good': 15, 'happy': 10, 'bar': 5})
>>> b = Counter({'menu': 1, 'good': 1, 'bar': 3})
>>> a + b
Counter({'menu': 21, 'good': 16, 'happy': 10, 'bar': 8})
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> Several mathematical operations are provided for combining Counter objects to produce multisets (counters that have counts greater than zero). Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or subtracting the counts of corresponding elements.

Note that if you want to save memory by modifying the `Counter` in-place rather than creating a new one, you can do `a.update(b)` or `b.update(a)`.

Comment: What if my values are 0? This operation seems skip them. I can only perform the addition if the values are at least 1. I am trying to prepare an always exact, default set of values for chart (0 is the amount that needs to be displayed).

How would I force to merge two counters if one of them has zero values to persist those?