# How to sum() the contents of multiple collections.Counter() objects with loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, counter

I have been researching this issue for a while, 
for solving **'combining'** ***multiple*** Counter().object or dicts; But still can`t work it done.
And I found two reference below:

- [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe)
- [Summing the contents of two collections.Counter() objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356055/summing-the-contents-of-two-collections-counter-objects)

For example I have many '*Counter Type*' variable name with order `[1 to 100]`:

```
Name:counter_1 Value:Counter({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
Name:counter_2 Value:Counter({'b':5, 'c':19, f:17})
Name:counter_3 Value:Counter({'a':11, 'b':22, 'c':33, 'd':97})
...
Name:counter_100 Value:Counter({'c':55, 'd':22, 'e':63, 'f':21})
```

If I add each of one manually `counter_1 + counter_2 + ... + counter_3`, it will make me insane.

Is there more elegant or easier way to **sum()** it all?
Thanks a million!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the built-in function `sum()`, and give it an appropriate starting value of an empty `Counter`.

```
>>> import collections
>>> c1 = collections.Counter({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
>>> c2 = collections.Counter({'b':5, 'c':19, 'f':17})
>>> sum((c1, c2), collections.Counter())
Counter({'c': 22, 'f': 17, 'b': 7, 'a': 1})
```

Comment: what if I have to sum from c1 to c100? tks

Comment: You put them all into a `list`. You should be doing that already. Do you really have separate variables `counter_1` through `counter_100`?

Comment: Yes. I tried something like(but Type Error) `sum(local()['counter_'+ str(i) for i in (1,100)], Counter())`. and I am also new in python.

Comment: Your first step should be avoiding making 100 separate named variables in the first place, and as TigerhawkT3 says, use a list (or a dictionary, depending on how much you care about the number).

Comment: Another question: how can I declare a `Counter Type` variable without any value? (When I consider avoiding making 100 separate named)

Comment: I tried`Test = Counter()`. Successful. Sorry for bothering