# Is there a command which will sort a Python list by data type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following list:

```
l = [True, 3, 7.3, (5,6), True, 'orange', 25, 'banana', False, (4,5), 9.2]
```

which contains a mixture of types:

```
for element in l:
    print (type(element))
```

output:

```
<class 'bool'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'bool'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'bool'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'float'>
```

Is there a command which will sort it according to types, that is, so the types land up in groups?

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. Is there a reason you have that list at all and not an object?

Comment: Actually, I am working with something with a much smaller number of types in it, which made me wonder if this was possible in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the string representation of the types for sorting:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: str(type(x)))
[True, True, False, 7.3, 9.2, 3, 25, 'orange', 'banana', (5, 6), (4, 5)]
```

Similar types will be **grouped** together maintaining the initial order in which they appeared.

In Python 2, type objects can be sorted directly, and you can pass `type` directly as the key function:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=type)
[True, True, False, 7.3, 9.2, 3, 25, 'orange', 'banana', (5, 6), (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 3):

a more readable solution would be ( along with the keys):

```
s = sorted([(x, x.__class__.__name__) for x in l], key=lambda x: x[1])
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @omu_negru's solution -

```
groups = dict()
for element in l:
    element_type = element.__class__.__name__
    if element_type not in groups:
        groups[element_type] = list()
    groups[element_type].append(element)
print(groups)
#  groups - {'bool': [True, True, False], 'float': [7.3, 9.2], 'int': [3, 25], 'str': ['orange', 'banana'], 'tuple': [(5, 6), (4, 5)]}
```