# Use Counter to count unique values in multiple lists

Tags: python, counter

I have a list of lists and I'm trying to use Counter to get the number of unique words across all of the lists.

```
[[‘My’,
‘name’,
 ‘is’,
 ‘Joe’],
[‘My’,
 ‘name’,
 ‘is’,
 ‘Sally’],
[‘My’,
 ‘name’,
 ‘is’,
 ‘Mike’]]
```

If it were just the first list I think I could do this:

```
counter_object = Counter(my_list[0])
keys = counter_object.keys()
num_values = len(keys)

print(num_values)
```

But unsure about doing this for multiple. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Edit: The expected output is 6. Because unique words ‘My’,
‘name’, ‘is’, 'Joe', 'Sally', 'Mike' total to 6.

Comment: What's the expected outputs in this case?

Comment: Sorry, the number 6 is expected.

Comment: OK - update my earlier post now with new info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summing the contents of two collections.Counter() objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356055/summing-the-contents-of-two-collections-counter-objects)

Comment: Is it necessary to use `Counter`? As the question is posed, there's no need to keep count of occurrences of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to count the **unique** items from each sublists.

```py
# MM = is your list
from collections import Counter   

def count_unique(M):
    flats = [x for sub in M for x in sub]
   
    counts = Counter(flats)

    return len(counts.keys())



print(count_unique(MM))     # check it 
# 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=chain#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to *flatten* the list, then use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

data = [
    ["My", "name", "is", "Joe"],
    ["My", "name", "is", "Sally"],
    ["My", "name", "is", "Mike"],
]

counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(data))
print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'My': 3, 'name': 3, 'is': 3, 'Joe': 1, 'Sally': 1, 'Mike': 1})
```

For more on how to flatten lists of lists, see the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists).

If you want the total of unique keys, on top of the counts, just do:

```
res = len(counts)
```

Note that if you only care about the total of uniques, you can directly use a set:

```
counts = set(chain.from_iterable(data))
print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
{'Sally', 'Mike', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Joe'}
```